# How do I activate an onclick event after entering a new URL (in the same domain)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a homepage with a register button. When clicked it displays a hidden div where the form is. I have a "Register" button in one of my inner pages of my website. Whenever it's clicked I want it to open the homepage and display the hidden register form without it being hidden. How can I do this?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="sprite sprite-btn-register"></a>
```

Comment: Add a parameter to the URL when you open it from the Register button. Then add code to the home page that checks for the URL parameter and shows the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar commented, a way could be to pass a parameter to the URL

Another possibility is to use [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

```
var x = document.referrer;
```

and checking on document.ready if you should hide or show your registration form, depending on referrer value.

Remember that HTTP referer is totally client side managed, so it could be hacked (if important in your case)

Answer (score 0):

use css in your hidden `<div id="reg">` `display:none;`

while click a link or button use `onclick="showDiv();"` to show that div

in js function

```
showDiv(){
 document.getElementById("reg").style="display:block;";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first adding id on within `<a>` just like

```
  <a href="http://www.example.com" id= "atagId" class="sprite sprite-btn-register"></a>
```

and then use this script

```
$('#atagId').click(function() {
var someId = $(this).attr("id");
window.open('SECOND.html/#'+someId);
  });
```